ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesop.labs'; 'mesop' is not a package
import mesop.labs as mel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mesop.labs'; 'mesop' is not a package

I have run below command
pip install mesop

but still its showing error
How should I solve this error ?
This is the orignial code
import time

import mesop as me
import mesop.labs as mel

@me.page(path="/text_to_text", title="Text I/O Example") # add /text_to_text this beside you local host link
def app():
  mel.text_to_text(
    upper_case_stream,
    title="Text I/O Example",
  )

def upper_case_stream(s: str):
  yield s.capitalize()
  time.sleep(0.5)
  yield "Done"



Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How are you running this script? What is your script name called?  Are you using the same python binary as the one associated with pip?

Post the output of these commands:
python --version
which python # Linux
where python # Windows
Get-Command python # Other Windows 

pip --version
which pip # Linux
where pip # Windows
Get-Command pip # Other Windows 

If you want to make sure that you install packages to use with the python binary you can always do python -m pip install package
